# Terminal login into lightdm

Tags: command-line, unity, lightdm, 16.10, vnc

If I start my Computer remotely and I want someone to access it with my account without saying them my password, I have to get VNC started and login.

Is there a way to manage that over ssh? So that I can login an account over the terminal?

I hope you can help me

Comment: Theoretical you can login via SSH, kill current Xsession, export local display and start new Xsession with `startx` or similarly.

Comment: Have you considered xdotool? I use `xdotool type "password" && xdotool key --clearmodifiers "Return"` to wake my computer from across the room.

Comment: @brndn2k If you make this an answer I will accept it! But xdotool key --clearmodifiers "Return" doesn't work. I used xdotool key KP_Enter, which works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate typing by using xdotool

`xdotool type "password" && xdotool key --clearmodifiers "Return"`

should type your password and then type the return key to submit the password

Comment: It is a cool solution, but it works only on X server-based displays, like **lock screen**. It does't work on the lightdm, which internally doesn't use the X server.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski LightDM does run an X server (that's why your answer works). GDM, for example, can run Wayland instead of X, and neither answer will work in that case. The problem is of accessing the X server with the right privileges.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an answer, that works under Ubuntu 16.04 with `lightdm`:

1. Make yourself `root` to get access to the lightdm's `.Xauthority`, which is located under `/var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority`. Either copy it somewhere where it will be readable by you and drop your root permissions, or simply remain root.
2. set `XAUTHORITY` to point to that file (e.g. `export XAUTHORITY=/var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority`)
3. set `DISPLAY` to the active display (`export DISPLAY=:0`)
4. `xdotool` should work now. Try

   ```
   xdotool type "My super secret password"
   xdotool key Return
   ```

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04 and up, Wayland is the default, so it will not accept `xdotool` commands. (just adding so future readers are aware of this.)