# Is it possible to login to desktop session from SSH?

Tags: ssh, login, vnc, remote

We have Ubuntu desktop 16.04 running on a remote workstation, and we have VNC access to it. This is great if the user account is logged in.

If the OS gets knocked out to the login screen, the VNC window becomes black and unusable.

We still have SSH and Telnet connectivity... Is there a way to force login of a user account via SSH remotely?

Comment: Use a different VNC server, vncserver allows separate logins. A better question is why are you forwarding an entire desktop ? You can forward single apps. FreeNX is faster and more secure. Web based solutions are better for server management.

Comment: we have a particular workflow that requires some users who aren't familiar with command line to perform some tasks in the GUI.

Comment: And security isn't a concern.

Comment: There is no way to log into the graphical interface over ssh.

Comment: Well, technically that strictly the case, but the desktop would be forwarded over ssh and not available to the local user. My suggestion is to enable auto login - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoLogin https://www.maketecheasier.com/enable-automatic-login-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

If you have root access, then (of course) everything is possible. One way of solving your the problem is to force login of the local graphical session, by typing the password into the login screen remotely via ssh. I know a way to do that in Xorg: https://askubuntu.com/a/1020172/55241. The Wayland will be another story.